# How can I enable/disable programatically added fields from a custom module?

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm trying to create a custom module for payment. When installed, the module automatically adds two fields to the '*Article*' content type.

I have 'enable/disable checkbox' in the form:

**Enable**: Should mean that people on my live website can use it

**Disable**: Should mean that no-one can use it (I don't want to remove the variables or the fields in the article content typ, I just want to hide everything in relation with the module)

Is there any hook or any thing that can do that?  Turn the module off?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but do you mean you want to turn your module off from inside its own code?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong yes dudde ^_^

Comment: When using the standard admin UI, once you disable your module, Drupal will never invoke it, which means any modifications to forms, like what you are describing here, will never take place. Why would you go through the extra trouble of duplicating this logic in your module, which I might add, will never have any effect, again, if the module is disabled?

Comment: I think you need to explain a little more about why you want to do this. You'll probably get a better answer if you describe the result you are trying to achieve rather than how you want to do it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want to enable/disable the module, as that would negate the point in writing it in the first place.  It sounds like you just want the option to disable the two fields you have created whilst keeping their data - is this correct?

Comment: @Chapabu exactly

Answer (score 0):

You should try `module_disable(array)` function. 
Here is the documentation for it. 
[Module Disable Programmatically](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7)

You should first check its existence by `module_exists` and you can also have a look at `drupal_uninstall_modules`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Indeed, as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13708875/1127583